# Soap UI shortcut to quickly select request in project window?

Tags: soapui

SOAP API vendor provides flow example as SOAP UI projects.

The best source of SOAP UI powerful usage is on a page: http://kjetilvalle.com/posts/soapui-less-painful.html

But I lack important shortcut to select current active request in Project panel. Like in NetBeans on `Ctrl+Shift+1` or like in IDEA on `Alt+F1 Enter`.

Is there Soap UI shortcut or GUI element for click to quickly select request in project window?

In my example I want move focus from request window to project window and blue mark should be moved to corresponding request (not that crossed):

[image]

Comment: If you want to open request, you may try `Enter` key when it is selected. If you want to fire the opened request, `Alt+Enter`. You may clearify if looking for different one.

Comment: `Enter` move focus from Project to Request window. I want *opposite action*. When I work on 20 projects with 100 request steps it is easy to be lost among projects / test suits and run wrong request...